# Mininet Connect CLI Without Using mn

Tags: mininet

Is there a way to connect a remote mininet controller cli without using

$ sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=[controller IP],port=[controller listening port]

command, because I have already created a custom topology on a remote host and want to connect its cli and test it on another python script, but mn command is creating new topology, which deletes my custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://mininet.org/walkthrough/#xterm-display

XTerm Display
For more complex debugging, you can start Mininet so that it spawns one or more xterms.

To start an xterm for every host and switch, pass the -x option:

$ sudo mn -x

Answer (score 0):

You can do both: Running your own topology and a remote controller with a single command like that:

> `sudo mn --custom myCustomTopo --topo myCustomTopo --controller remote`

Where myCustomTopo.py and myCustomTopo.mn is the Topology files.

Generally, after sudo mn with `-- option` you can add whatever option you want to add to mininet emulation. For example writing `sudo mn --mac` the hosts take mac in row  00:00:00:00:00:01 for h1 02 for h2 etc.

Hope that helps.